# How to TypeScript a props interface containing an object and merge with defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a TypeScript props interface like such:

```
interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  components?: object;
  mode: string;
  actions: {
    copy: boolean;
    code: boolean;
    refresh: boolean;
    source: boolean;
  };
  source?: string;
  readonly withStyles?: object;
  styles?: object;
}
```

And I have a corresponding defaultProps interface as such:

```
class Box extends Component<Props, State> {
  public static defaultProps = {
    mode: 'full',
    actions: {
      copy: true,
      code: true,
      refresh: true,
      source: true,
    },
  };

  ....

}
```

A user should be able to specify only a partial set of `actions` on a component and the rest should be merged from `defaultProps`.

For instance if a user specifies:

`<Box actions={{ copy: false }} />`

I expect that defaultProps would fill in the gap to produce `props.actions` as `{ copy: false, code: true, refresh: true, source: true }`.

However, I currently get a TypeScript error: `Type '{ copy: boolean; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ copy: boolean; code: boolean; refresh: boolean; source: boolean; }': code, refresh, source`.

**How can I get this to work properly?**

```
TypeScript v.3.2.2
@types/react v16.8.2
```

Comment: TypeScript 3.0 apparently solved the not reading from `defaultProps` issue, but I cannot find an example that has an object in the props. The examples are too simplified. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-0/#default-props-support

Comment: Note: I know that I can merge the defaultProps with props. That will totally work, but this makes no sense to actually have to do. TypeScript should be doing this for me. Maybe this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't have deep defaultProps checking/merging and TypeScript will not change that.

One way of handling this is making wrapper component:

```
//pure js

const defaultActions = {
  copy: true,
  paste: false
};

const Box = props => JSON.stringify(props);
const BoxWithDefaultActions = ({ actions, ...rest }) => (
  <Box actions={{ ...defaultActions, ...actions }} {...rest} />
);

const App = () => (
  <>
      <Box actions={{ copy: false }} />
      <BoxWithDefaultActions actions={{ copy: false }} />
  </>
);

/**
Box:
  { "actions": { "copy": false } }
Box with actions:
  { "actions": { "copy": false, "paste": false } }
**/

//HOC or render props component could be even better "solution".
```

You can read more about this in 
React Github Issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2568